# Building an iPad App with HTML5 content using Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios

I'm a rookie in iOS development. I want to insert an HTML5 local page into an iPad App. I tried some tutorials but they didn't work.

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/loading-local-files-into-uiwebview/

In summary, make a uiwebview, get the local file URL from NSFileManager, load the URL.